# Vue and Vuex: Handling dependent computed properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

My application is a cut-down spreadsheet built in Vue with Vuex.  The key components are `TableCollection`, `Table` and `Row`.  The `TableCollection` has an array with multiple `Table` objects.  Each `Table` has an array with multiple `Row` objects.

The `Row` component has a property named `calculatedField`.  This simply combines two fields in the row to produce a third field.  My options are to implement `calculatedField` as a computed property, local to the `Row` component, or as a getter in the Vuex store.

The `Table` component requires a `subTotal` value, which is calculated by adding the `calculatedField` for all rows in the table.  As you can see, the `subTotal` calculation is dependent on the `calculatedField` calculation.

If I implement `calculatedField` as a local computed property of `Row`, it is cached.  The problem is however that I can't seem to access the calculated field from a `Table` parent.  I tried the following in `Table`:

```
computed : {
    subTotal : function () {
        let total = 0;
        this.table.rows.forEach(function (row) {
           total += row.calculatedField;
        });
        return total;
    }
}
```

The result was NaN.

One solution would be to duplicate the logic from `calculatedField` in the computed property of `Table`, but that's not DRY.

The other alternative would be to implement both `subTotal` and `calculatedField` as getters in the store, however this would mean passing arguments to the gettter (`tableId`, `rowId`, or both), and so the results would not be cached.  This seems really inefficient.

The final possibility is that I implement my `calculatedField` logic in a global helper or mixin.  This would avoid code duplication and getter inefficiency, but doesn't feel quite right - the code relates specifically to `Table` and `Row`, and would ideally be kept there.

Are there other solutions I have overlooked?  What is the ideal 'Vue-way'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance is an issue and caching is important right now, you might want to **implement caching on the `Table` component**.

In the **Row** component, emit the new value so the parent component can cache it.

```
  computed: {
    calculatedField() {
      const result = this.data.field + this.data.other;
      this.$emit('change', this.data.id, result);
      return result;
    }
  },
```

In the **Table** component, handle the event and cache the new values.

```
  data() {
    return { cache: {} };
  },
  computed: {
    subTotal() {
      return Object.values(this.cache).reduce((total, value) => total + value, 0);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(rowId, val) {
      // important for reactivity
      this.$set(this.cache, rowId, val);
    }
  },
```

When a `Row`'s data is updated, it triggers a change event with the new calculated value and the parent `Table` keeps track of the calculated values, using this cache to get the subtotal.

You can see in the following example that the computed properties are hit once, then on row changes (click the Rand button), only the relevant computed properties are refreshed.

```js
const MyRow = {
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  computed: {
    calculatedField() {
      console.log("row computed for", this.data.id);
      const result = this.data.field + this.data.other;
      this.$emit('change', this.data.id, result);
      return result;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      this.data.other = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    }
  },
  template: `
    <tr>
        <td>{{ data.field }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.other }}</td>
        <td>{{ calculatedField }}</td>
        <td><button type="button" @click="onClick">Rand</button></td>
    </tr>
  `
};

const MyTable = {
  props: {
    rows: {
      type: Array
    }
  },
  components: {
    MyRow
  },
  data() {
    return {
      cache: {}
    }
  },
  computed: {
    subTotal() {
      console.log("Table subTotal");
      return Object.values(this.cache).reduce((total, value) => total + value, 0);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(rowId, val) {
      console.log("onChange", rowId, val);
      this.$set(this.cache, rowId, val);
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
        <table border="1">
            <tr><th>field</th><th>other</th><th>calculated</th><th></th></tr>
            <my-row v-for="row in rows" @change="onChange" :key="row.id" :data="row"></my-row>
        </table>
        Subtotal: {{ subTotal }}
    </div>
  `
};

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    MyTable
  },
  data: {
    rows: [{
        id: 1,
        field: 1,
        other: 1
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        field: 2,
        other: 2
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        field: 3,
        other: 3
      },
    ]
  },
  template: `<my-table :rows="rows"></my-table>`
});
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
```