# Vue.js update subtotal in array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties

After some research i find this post what have an example about how to manage a complex array in Vue.js
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuex-best-practices-for-complex-objects/10143/2

I have create this jsbin (https://jsbin.com/jocezud/5/edit?html,js,output) to make some test but i´m stuck at this point. I want to make some totals based in the checked topics:

**A)** When the checkbox of each **Topic** is checked the `price` value must be *copied* to the `subTotal` value.

**B)** Also every user must have the `userTotal` updated with the sum of the `subTotal` of the checked **Topics**.

Here is a capture about my goal.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not creating an independent component, which displays one list item each? In this component, you can easily create e. g. a computed property to show the subtotal based on which "topics" are selected.

Comment: Here's an answer of mine where I explain how to [handle computations on complex dynamic arrays with caching in Vue components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49743714/1218980).

Comment: Is it possible that a topic listed in a user.topics array would also be found in another user's topics array? E.g. Tom has topic 2 and Andres has topic 2, as well well?

Comment: @Forty3 Nope, in this scenario each topic only can stay associated to a single user

Comment: @BennettDams My goal is have the arrays always updated because i need the data for a future actions. As far i know, i can´t use computed actions to have an array value updated, only to render it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i get it working with also a `Final total` and a `Reset` feature.

Here is the actual working version (https://jsbin.com/jocezud/12/edit?html,js,output)

Anyway i think there must be a better way to, in this case run some calculations of data in arrays when a array value change happens, right?